# Avalonia + ReactiveUI - pharmacist for Events() generation

Tags: reactiveui, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to get my head around Avalonia in general, and the Reactive UI integration in particular. From googling around, I understand that Avalonia pulled away the Avalonia support in ReactiveUI, and tries to integrate ReactiveUI into Avalonia itself, to support a sometimes unstable Avalonia API.

I'm implementing a flow where a double tap on a DataGrid row should open a details windows, which I can do by adding a handler for the DoubleTapped event in the code behind. However, I was wondering if I could do this in a Reactive UI way, in a WhenActivated() implementation, by observing the DoubleTapped event.

In the ReactiveUI documentation, I see that there is a Pharmacist integration, which generates the observables for these events. However, when I fetch a reference to the DataGrid in the code behind, and try to hook into the DoubleTapped via
`myDataGrid.Events(). ...`, I don't get to see any events. Does this imply that there's no such support in Avalonia at this time?

Finally, while I'm at it, if I forget about the Reactive UI support, and use a straight-forward event handler, I need to do some stuff to detect whether it was a row that was double tapped, or something else (such as the header). I have to do this, because there's no EventSetter implementation in Avalonia as I understand it.

Somebody who knows if Avalonia will support this in the future?

Edit: in the end I used ReactiveUI somewhat similar to

```
TreeView.GetObservable(DoubleTappedEvent)
                .Subscribe(async x =>
                {
                    var selectedItem = TreeView.SelectedItem;
                    if (selectedItem is TreeNodeViewModel treeNodeViewModel)
                    {
                        await ViewModel!.ActivateResource(treeNodeViewModel);
                    }
                }).DisposeWith(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

An attached behaviour can also help to bind events to perform logic. There is a sample that looks like it could work provided the `DoubleTappedEvent` is being fired.

[Avalonia Docs - Creating and binding Attached Properties](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/creating-and-binding-attached-properties)

The dev tools should help show the event your are looking for tunnel and bubble though the DataGrid?

[image: AvaloniaUI Dev tools showing the DoubleTapped event]

Comment: The link provided seems to be dead . Anyway, in the end I registered for the DoubleTapped event indeed using the ReactiveUI tools, as shown in my edited question.

Comment: Docs link has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Pharmacist does not support Avalonia. They are working on `ReactiveMarbles.ObservableEvents`, which as of right now, doesn't work on generic classes, but they're working on fixing it.